# Flask-SQLAlchemy update only increasing values

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've stumbled across an issue I can't seem to figure out.

I have a database (ideally) filled with entries as follows:

```
{id:1,name:"<somename>", value:1}
{id:2,name:"<somename>", value:2}
{id:3,name:"<somename>", value:3}
{id:4,name:"<somename>", value:4}
{id:5,name:"<somename>", value:5}
```

If I want to increment the value for each one, starting at a given value N i know I can do.

```
OBJECT.filter(Task.vaue>=N).update({Task.value:Task.value+1})
```

However,
The reality is my database looks like this:

```
{id:1,name:"<somename>", value:1}
{id:2,name:"<somename>", value:2}
{id:3,name:"<somename>", value:3}
{id:4,name:"<somename>", value:5}
{id:5,name:"<somename>", value:10}
```

I would like to start at a value N, and only increment values where the previous entry's value is M = N-1. For example:

BEFORE:

```
{id:1,name:"<somename>", value:1}
{id:2,name:"<somename>", value:2}
{id:3,name:"<somename>", value:3}
{id:4,name:"<somename>", value:5}
{id:5,name:"<somename>", value:10}
```

N=1 AFTER:

```
{id:1,name:"<somename>", **value:2**}
{id:2,name:"<somename>", **value:3**}
{id:3,name:"<somename>", **value:4**}
{id:4,name:"<somename>", **value:5**}
{id:5,name:"<somename>", value:10}
```

Or another example: BEFORE

```
{id:1,name:"<somename>", value:1}
{id:2,name:"<somename>", value:2}
{id:3,name:"<somename>", value:3}
{id:4,name:"<somename>", value:5}
{id:5,name:"<somename>", value:10}
```

N=3 AFTER:

```
{id:1,name:"<somename>", value:1}
{id:2,name:"<somename>", value:2}
{id:3,name:"<somename>", **value:4**}
{id:4,name:"<somename>", **value:5**}
{id:5,name:"<somename>", value:10}
```

Comment: In your first example, how can line `{id:1,name:"<somename>", value:1}` apply to the rule "only increment values where the previous entry's value is M = N-1", if there is no "previous" entry for this line? Or your task states that line with N changes no matter what, but the rule above apply only to subsequent lines, so your algorithm changes at minimum 1 line no matter what?

Comment: Second. As I can see, your first and second examples have conflicts. Your second example states, that algorithm finds line id=3, value=3 and changes value from 3 to 4, so line with id=4, value=5 starts to apply to the rule M=N-1. But if we apply the same algorithm to the first example, it will execute in this manner: finds line id=1, value=1, change value from 1 to 2, but then line with id=2 won't apply to the rule and won't be changed because now your state is: 
`{id:1, value:2}
{id:2, value:2}` that won't apply to M=N-1 for the line with id=2